# The best optimal way to find the frequency in a very very long string

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, lookup-tables

I have to find a very optimal way to find the frequency of a character in a  very very long file containing words,(cases are ignored, should count both Lower case and Upper case) using C/C++. 
I already know one which is this (here i am reading input from user at terminal but in my case i will be reading from file, so please do not go to gets() function, please focus on my main objective which is to get a more optimized way than this (if any is possible) ):

```
int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int c = 0, count[26] = {0};

   printf("Enter a string\n");
   gets(string);

   while (string[c] != '\0')
   {
      /** Considering characters from 'a' to 'z' only
          and ignoring others */

      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') 
         count[string[c]-'a']++;

      c++;
   }

   for (c = 0; c < 26; c++)
   {
      /** Printing only those characters 
          whose count is at least 1 */

      if (count[c] != 0)
         printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c + 'a', count[c]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But i want to optimize it some more than this because it has to work for a very very long file containing a lot of words, Could some one please give me any suggestion or ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's c++. c++ and c are not the same.

Comment: Obligatory note: while `gets` might well good enough for this project, using it is a bad idea in general for security reasons. I won't go into detail in this comment, but Google it. (`fgets` is a replacement)

Comment: I think your approach is correct... instead of `gets()` you need to open file and fetch strings using `fgets()`... why i think your approach is correct because you need to traverse you complete file at least once to know all the characters in the file.

Comment: @iharob ,Ok thanks.. i ahve done the changes question accordingly. But my main focus is on algorithms or logic.

Comment: The computation inside the while loop is already bare minimum, I don't see how it can be minimized even further. The only optimization that can be done is before the while loop. For example, allocating enough memory to load large chunks of file at a time, playing with turning off buffering, etc.

Comment: You might gain something by precomputing `string[c]-'a'` and using the result, but that depends on the compiler.

Comment: Your program will be I/O bound. It makes zero sense to ever think of optimizing the computation part. It's a complete waste of time.

Comment: U can use map in C++ for character count. Can save alot of comparisons.

Comment: @user2979190: nope; a `map` is going to be way slower (O(n log n) with relatively big constants and bad cache locality) than a plain array lookup (O(1) with small constants - it's just a handful of assembly instructions - and the best possible cache locality for small arrays).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks for pointing out. My Bad :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotic complexity doesn't get any better, and in general the algorithm is already mostly at the bare minimum.

The single most important change you can make is to call less frequently IO functions (and you are *not* going to call `gets` for real); use `fread` and read in a big (say, 4 KB) buffer - larger sizes are usually not beneficial.

Depending on the CPU and cache, if you already had the whole string in memory it may gain you something to just make `count` 256 elements long and avoid the `if` for alphabetical characters (trading one less branch prediction spot for bigger cache occupation). But I doubt this could be even measurable - your code should now be completely IO-bound, with the CPU time needed for processing being completely negligible compared to the wait for the disk reads.

Comment: thanks for the answer, What is the complexity of the current code ? IS it linear ? as i am going to read the file /string buffer.

Comment: Yes, it's linear (you are performing a constant-time operation - the array lookup - for each character of the string).

Comment: I/O kept apart (as it will indeed completely dominate), removing the two comparisons will make a big difference as they involve unpredictable branches (possibly speedup x2 or x3 for such a tiny loop body).

Comment: @MatteoItalia On last doubt i have to clear from this question please, explain me "count[string[c]-'a']++;" this line , Lets say i have got "r" at current index whose acii is 114 and a has ascii value 97 , so now the count array would be count[114-97]++ , which is count[17]++ right ? Please correct me if i am wrong ?